# Transfer of fees from one event to another

Tags: civievent

How can I transfer an event fee for a contact from one event to another?  We have a contact that registered for two different events. She decided after registering that she can not attend both so she wants to apply her registration fee from the event she will not attend to the other.

Answer (score 2):

CiviEvent have a setting called `Allow Self-service cancellation or transfer` option for event which I think might be helpful in this case. To find this, check the Online Registration tab on Event Configuration.

URL - `civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=<event_id>`

[image]

With this option enabled a participant gets a unique link in the registration confirmation mail where he/she can transfer the participant to some other contact.

It is included in 4.7 version. [Check this](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Self+service+view%2C+update+and+cancel+for+CiviEvent+and+improvements+to+event+badges?focusedCommentId=84639766) for more info.

Comment: I have the same question as Terri and I think the self-service transfer is not the solution to the question. The desire is to transfer a payment from one event registration to another, of the same participant.